# Swift: Autoplay video in collectionViewCell when visible and top of visibleCells

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to autoplay videos (similar to Twitter's implementation) when the collectionViewCell becomes visible and is somewhere around the center of the screen. When that video cell scrolls past the center, that video should pause, and the new center cell's video should start playing.

My datasource has a mix of videos and images, so I have to manage the different media type accordingly by hiding or showing the imageView or videoView. My current implementation works in displaying the content correctly, but the autoplaying isn't guaranteed.

Code:

```
// At TweetCell
var tweet: Tweet? {
    didSet {
        if let tweet = tweet {

            //Main image/video
            if let mediaType = tweet.mediaType {
                if mediaType == "photo" {
                    
                    ///Toggle image/video view
                    imageView.isHidden = false
                    videoView.isHidden = true
                    
                    let url = URL(string: tweet.imageUrlString)
                    imageView.sd_setImage(with: url)
                    
                } else if mediaType == "video" {

                    ///Toggle image/video view
                    imageView.isHidden = true
                    videoView.isHidden = false
                    
                    guard let videoVariantsArray = tweet.videoVariantsArray else {return}
                    guard let url = URL(string: getBestVideo(variants: videoVariantsArray)) else {return}
                    
                    player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                    player?.isMuted = true
                    let castedLayer = videoView.layer as! AVPlayerLayer
                    castedLayer.player = player
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// To reset tweetCell
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    
    tweet = nil

    imageView.image = nil
    imageView.isHidden = false
    videoView.isHidden = true
    player = nil
}

//At CollectionView
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tweets?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TweetCell
    cell.tweet = tweets?[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let visibleCells = collectionView.visibleCells
    let currentCell = visibleCells.first as? TweetCell
    
    if currentCell?.tweet?.mediaType == "video" {
        currentCell?.player?.play()
    }
    
    print("---")
    print("Current", currentCell?.tweet?.text)
    print("New Cell", tweetCell.tweet.text)

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let tweetCell = cell as? TweetCell else {return}
    
    if tweetCell.tweet?.mediaType == "video" {
        
        //Pause video when cell end displaying
        tweetCell.player?.pause()
    }
}
```

The intent of the implementation above, is to autoplay the video (if it is a video) when it is the first cell within the visibleCell array. However when printing the first cell, it is not guaranteed that the first cell is actually the correct cell as displayed on the screen.

For example, if the tweets array is like so:

```
Tweet(text: "1",  mediaType: "photo"),
Tweet(text: "2",  mediaType: "video"),
Tweet(text: "3",  mediaType: "video"),
Tweet(text: "4",  mediaType: "video"),
Tweet(text: "5",  mediaType: "photo"),
```

We expect the prints to be:

```
---
Current: 1
New cell: 2 
---
Current: 2
New cell: 3
---
Current: 3
New cell: 4
---
Current: 4
New cell: 5
```

However, the prints tend to turn out like so. Note that on screen, it is displayed correctly as above:

```
---
Current: 1
New cell: 2 
---
Current: 2 <===
New cell: 3
---
Current: 2 <=== Because this isn't 3, autoplaying of video 3 tends to fail
New cell: 4
---
Current: 4
New cell: 5
```

I have done the necessary `prepareForReuse`, but it appears that the cell doesn't reuse properly.

How do I implement the autoplay correctly?

Comment: Can you implement prepareForReuse logic in cellForRow? For center play logic. First you need to check if user is not scrolling. If not then get either center element of cell array or check cell frame from the screen containing center Y.

Comment: @AmberK I do not quite understand the second part, "check if user is not scrolling...". Is there a short code snippet that you can share? Thanks.